# Display object information based on selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular for a SPA I'm working on. I have an array which contains objects for each user on my site. I have an ng-repeat to add all the users to my dropdown list. I'm trying to figure out how do I display specific user information in an input box based on the selected user from the drop down?

```
<select id="entityDropDown" ng-options="user.name for user in users" ng-change="userInfo(user)"></select>


<div>
   <label for="entityId">ID: </label>
   <input type="text" id="entityId" disabled ng-model="{{user.id}}"/>
   </br>
   <label for="entityDomain">Domain: </label>
   <input type="text" id="entityDomain" disabled ng-model="{{user.domain}}"/>
</div>

app.controller('userCtrl', 
    function userCtrl($scope,siteCollection){
        $scope.users = siteCollection.getUsers();

    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

K I solved the issue.

First of all, this `ng-model="{{user.domain}}"` isn't how you use ng-model. I had to change them to  remove the curly braces `ng-model="user.domain"`.

I modified the select as such:

```
<select id="entityDropDown" 
    ng-model="selectedUser" 
    ng-options="user as user.name for user in users" 
    ng-change="userInfo(selectedUser)">
</select>
```

This is my controller function:

```
spApp.controller('userCtrl', 
    function userCtrl($scope,siteCollection){
        $scope.users = siteCollection.getUsers();
        $scope.selectedUser = {};
        $scope.userInfo = function(user) {
            $scope.selectedUser = user;
        };

    }
);
```

Basically the controller gets all my users and puts it in a user object. The select goes through each user and generates the options. When the selected option changes, the ng-change passes the selected user object to the userInfo function and the html populates with that objects information.

Answer (score 0):

you can append `ng-model="selectedUser"` to your select and in your `userCtrl`

```
<!-- template.html -->
<select id="entityDropDown" ng-options="user as user.name for user in users" ng-model="selectedUser">
</select>

<div class="user-info" ng-show="selectedUser">
   <p> {{selectedUser.name}}</p>
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

in your controller

```
// controller.js
function userCtrl($scope, siteCollection){
    $scope.users = siteCollection.getUsers();
    $scope.$watch('selectedUser', function(oldVal, newVal) {
       if (oldVal === newVal) return;
       //do something like call JSON if need it
    });
}
```

When the `<select>` changes the `$scope.selectedUser` changes to selected value. later you can use the `selectedUser` variable like holder for your show the info into other place like  in the `div.user-info` or you can use `$scope.$watch('selectedUser'...` for fire other behavior like call a services or whatever

using your template

```
<select id="entityDropDown" ng-options="user in users" ng-model="selectedUser">
   <!-- <option ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</option> -->
</select>

<div>
   <label for="entityId">ID: </label>
   <input type="text" id="entityId" disabled ng-model="selectedUser.id"/>
   </br>
   <label for="entityDomain">Domain: </label>
   <input type="text" id="entityDomain" disabled ng-model="selectedUser.domain"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry,I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I get this error: Syntax Error: Token 'selectedUser.id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{selectedUser.id}}] starting at [selectedUser.id}}]

Comment: @Batman pointed out my mistake `{{}}` is for interpolate. i've updated and also the sintax on `ng-repeat`